# XCode 6.1 NSString.boundingRectWithSize Compile Error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

After I updated Xcode to 6.1 I get a couple of Compiler errors for my existing project.

I defined attributes like

```
let styleAttriutes = [
  NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(...),
  NSForgeroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blackColor()
]
```

**Error:** "Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments"

So I declared the inferred Dictionary explicit adding **: [NSString : Any]** since all the key constants are of type `NSString` and we have different values: `UIFont` / `UIColor` and `AnyObject` is also not allowed.

```
let styleAttriutes : [NSString : Any] = [ ...
```

Now the compiler is happy in this point.

The defined attribues are used in

```
text.boundingRectWithSize(size: CGSize, options: NSStringDrawingOptions, attributes: [NSObject : AnyObject!], context: NSStringDrawingContext!)
```

Since attributes of type `[NSObject:AnyObject!]` are expected but I hand over attribues of type `[NSString : Any]` the compiler complains:

**Error**: "'NSString' is not identical to 'NSObject'"

I tried to cast it using `attributes as [NSObject : AnyObject]` but then I get runtime error.

**Fatal Error**: "Can't unsafeBitCast between types of differenz sizes".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you're using `UIFont`'s `init` method which returns an optional (i.e. can return `nil`) since Xcode 6.1.

So try replacing `UIFont(...)` with `UIFont(...)!`.

Comment: God man, this is so confusing. Compiler reports so funny errors! Thanks!